# automorphism $(Z/2Z)^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am preparing for an exam in elementary group theory and while studying a proof by my professor, I came across something I just don't seem to understand. In his proof he claims that, considering a map from $(Z/2Z)^n$ to itself ($Z$ being the set of integers), the correspondence $(x_1 , ... , x_n)\to(x_2 , ... , x_n , x_1)$ is an isomorphism. Why is this correspondence an isomorphism?

Also, is it true that the correspondence $(x_1 , ... , x_n)\to(x_{a_1}, ... , x_{a_{n-1}} , x_{a_n})$, where $0 < a_i < n+1$ and $a_i = a_j <=> i=j$, is also an isomorphism from $(Z/2Z)^n$ to itself?

Comment: What is the definition of an isomorphism you are working with?

Comment: The definition I am working with is: a bijective map f: G -> H that satisfies f(xy)=f(x)f(y) for all x,y in G.

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. You say 'automorphism' in the title, 'isomorphism' in the text, and the definition you just gave me is that of a homomorphism!

Comment: You asked for the definition of an isomorphism which I am familiar with, which is the definition stated above. A homomorphism is defined similarily in my textbooks, with the difference that the map need not be bijective. In my post, I choose to use the word isomorphism, because that is also the word my professor used in his proof, whereas I choose automorphism in the title to make it more compact. I hope this clears your confusion! Please correct me if I'm mixing things up here!

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean you did anything wrong. I meant exactly what I typed: that I am personally confused.

Answer (score 2):

Hints

Fill in details :

Observe that $\;G:=\left(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right)^n\;$ can be seen as a vector space over the field $\;\Bbb F_2:=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$, with the obvious termwise addition and scalar product.

Then, an automorphism of the abelian group $\;G\;$ is the same as an automorphism of the vector space $\;G_{\Bbb F_2}\;$ , and the map you show there is the one determined by the linear operator changing any ordered basis $\;\{e_1,...,e_n\}\;$ into the ordered basis $\;\{e_2,...,e_n,e_1\}\;$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As it contains some notions I am not quite familiar with, I would appreciate the clarification of certain statements. First of all, is it true that by vector space over the field $Z/2Z$, you mean all vectors in $R^n$ which coordintates assume values from $Z/2Z$? Is $G_{F_2}$ simply a different (compact) notation for this vector field? Unfortunately, I don't understand the last statement, that is "and the map you show...", at all.

Comment: @Tyron Nop! There is no relation in this context between $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ and $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ *besides the facts* they both are sets, fields...but one is infinite, the other one very finite, they have different characteristics, etc. Yes, that definition is like writing $\;V_\Bbb C\;$ for a linear space **over** the field $\;\Bbb C\;$, etc. The last statement is the very juice of this beverage: it means your *group* automorphism is just a *linear operator* on that linear space (group) and since it maps a basis to a basis it automatically is an automorphism (as the lin. space is fin. dimens.)